# How to set gazebo log dir to a different destination then ~/.gazebo/log

Tags: gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I am logging state.log from gazebo-9. But however it insists logging under .gazebo/log.

Is there any way I can set the log dir to a different directory, similar to ROS_LOG_DIR  in ros?

Best regards,
C.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/25013/how-to-set-gazebo-log-dir-to-a-different-destination-then-%7E/.gazebo/log/) by [altineller](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/23788/altineller/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 9 on 2020-05-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

If you're logging from the command line, you can pass the `--record-path` flag.

If you're doing it through the C++ API, you can pass the [path](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/11.0.0/classgazebo_1_1util_1_1LogRecord.html#aa00651928e9fe26bdce96e0d90124084) to `LogRecord::Start`.

If you're triggering it through a message, you can use the `base_path` [field](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/msg-api/9.0.0/log__control_8proto.html).

If you're using ROS 1, pass `extra_gazebo_args:="--record-path <path>"` to `empty_world.launch`.

If you're using ROS 2, pass `record_path` to `gzserver.launch.py`.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2020-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [altineller](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/23788/altineller/) on 2020-05-04**:
Hello @chapulina I am launching gazebo trough a launch file, in ros.  and the ros gazebo arguments do not include record-path. is there a way I can still use ros, and give this command line argument?

best

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2020-05-04**:
I updated the answer to include ROS